# Check Bluetooth version in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to get the Bluetooth version in an Android device.

Is there any way to determine the Bluetooth version in an Android device programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, it's not possible using the Android API. You are only able to check if Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth LE is available.

As described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)  , it can be done via the PackageManager.hasSystemFeature().

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH)
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)
```